# Is it always possible to make comments/edits in an anonymous way?

Tags: support

Say, I want to edit a question by an OP to show how to improve it. For various reasons, I do not want to reveal who is making this suggestion.

Is it possible?

Comment: You want to make anonymous edits to someone else's post? What could go wrong.

Comment: @Organic Marble, me in particular, no. The reason I asked is because I was explained that "closers" prefer to silently vote to (vote without explanations, examples of edits) is because they don't want to reveal their ID. I just want to know, if you want to help but for some reasons (not my case) you want to do it anonimously, is it possible?

Comment: That would open the door to all kinds of abuse. I of course accept 100% that your motives are pure, but not everyone's would be.

Comment: @Organic Marble, so it is possible or not?

Comment: I don't think so. You *might* be able to hide behind the Community Bot thing but I am not clear on how that works. The mods would/could still know who did it.

Comment: @Organic Marble, me neither ... but it looks possible, either to help in good faith (but for some reasons wanting to remain anonimous (I can't understand why neither), or to abuse (?)

Comment: @NgPh no system is perfect, but being open to the entire internet means certain things have been found to keep things from going crazy and bad actors from wreaking absolute havoc. One of them is keeping activity visibly linked to the users. It's one of the things that makes the almost 200 different Stack Exchange sites and millions of users somehow work together to make magic.

Answer (score 5):

There's a site setting that staff can disable called "allow anonymous edit suggestions" - it's enabled on all sites by default. So a logged-out user can make edit suggestions (that will go through the suggested edit review queue).

So, the answer to your question is... kinda. You, as a logged in user, can not make edits anonymously. If you log out, you can make edit suggestions but these must be approved by reviewers or the poster themselves to be accepted.

To answer the semi-un-asked "why" - we are a community-curated platform and that means that we feel that - failing any known abuse on a site - we want to make it as simple as possible for someone to improve the content here. An expert may find a solution they find is excellent but needs some minor edits for content or clarity or some resources to support an answer but may not have an account.

While the chances are low, we don't generally see people abusing this and the review process usually prevents problematic edits from ever actually being live on the site.

Comment: I think that such edits might not be 100% absolutely anonymous to moderators/staff who still have access to IP addresses and browser/OS information.

Comment: @uhoh, I don't think that the motivation of  "questions closers" to remain anonymous is to hide their ID from anybodyelse, except from OP. Their ID are disclosed to many, EXCEPT TO THE OP. I suspect that the motivation could be to avoid the "retaliation syndrome" (which is nonsense to me, as a well-worded expression of  disagreement is supposed to improve your post). No system is perfect, but a system that gives support to such fear is imperfect. Being not able to justify the verdict openly, many prefer obscurity. Transparency is the pilar of a democratic process, barring general elections.

Comment: Allow me to  further illustrate my thought. I got a downvote to my question above "Say,... Is this possible?". I got 2 commenters (uhoh and Organic Marble). If any of the two says, "I downvoted and this is why", it would be very helpful, because I can take note of the explicit reason of disliking the question (that I may or may not agree with). But if there is a 3rd person, then I am "stuck". This is my demonstration that opacity doesn't help in a democratic process. Invoking opacity as a MUST for SE needs more convincing arguments than "read the rules".

Comment: @Catija Stack Exchange rocks! I can't figure out what NgPh's concern is, I often don't understand people. My comment is simply my inane pedantry; I saw a statement that looked incomplete and suggested some refinement.

Comment: @NgPh If you're trying to divine identities of down voters, I think that's a road that leads nowhere except doom and gloom. There are always random, unexplained down votes, just ignore them and just keep asking and answering. But since you are curious, [here's a screenshot indicating that I upvoted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykgpf.png) what I think is the question you talked about, and overall in Space SE I [up vote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWgPF.png) 70x more than I [downvote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bruw.png) & quite [generous with helpful comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hjG0.png)

Comment: @uhoh, thanks for this, but it doesn't change my concern by a iota. It even misconstrued the problem. It is not about "curiosity". It is simply about what does the principle of opacity bring as benefit to the community (in particular for the votes to close)? As some call it a "tenet", it must have a rationale behind. Does anybody have an answer to this question (or point me to the part of the Guidelines giving its rationale)?

Comment: As @uhoh has often commented (correctly, often) that my questions are convoluted. Allow me to recall how I came to this particular one. It started with the explanation to me that "silent **voters to close**" want to preserve their anonymity. It is also explained that "close" is in fact to help the OP (which is true). Therefore I ask, is there a way to help, while not wanting to reveal your ID (the rationale of which I don't understand)? It turns out, from this answer that there is a way. If a system leaves the choice between opacity and transparency, many will choose opacity ...

Comment: ... Let's be clear, a democratic system cannot be based on open votings only. But there are cases that require open voting only. Take a parliament voting on a law project. Take a committee voting on a technical standard. Take a Supreme Court voting on an appeal. In these cases a verdict is accompanied by a justification text. Because the aim is not only to deliver a verdict, but to consolidate the Law. Asking an OP to guess how to improve his closed question, to the liking of 5 self-nominated judges, w/o justifications, is puzzling. Is there a reason for that? I wish it is written somewhere.

Comment: @NgPh The OP does not have to justify to the ~5 who voted to close. The OP just has to justify to the community at large. Any 5 votes in the community can reopen the question. It doesn't have to be the same people who closed it.

Comment: @NgPh And if the OP needs to make an appeal, they can create a post here on meta providing their justification for why their question is fit to reopen. That is a good way to get visibility if there's not a lot of eyes on the closed question.

Comment: @NgPh If a close/reopen war occurs (which is extremely rare), anyone can flag for moderator intervention.

Comment: @called2voyage, thanks for your helpful clarification. It's a fair point that I overlooked. But it doesn't negate my point that anonymous voting to close forces the OP to make guesswork, in the case the OP decides to edit the question, and at least equally in the case the OP takes the route of escalating the issue. Your explanation doesn't touch on the question of the value of anonymous voting neither.